# League of Legend cursor resizing does not work properly

Tags: wine, cursor

There are settings in the League of Legends that allow adjust the cursor size. The cursor size can be adjusted from 0 to 100. The default value is set to 50. However, when the setting is more than 50, the cursor size does not change. Only settings below 50 will respond. In other words, the cursor size can not exceed the default. It is possible to make the cursor size smaller, but it is impossible to make the cursor size larger. Is there a solution to this?